# How to add a user's selected image to an SMS Intent?

Tags: java, android

Ideally, I'd have liked to be able to use the SMS manager to send photos to a predetermined phone number without having to open an intent to the default SMS app on the phone, but failing that, I give this scenario:

I want to be able to open an intent to the default SMS app on a phone, pre-populating it with a phone number to send to, a default text header in the message, and a photo that the user has just taken or selected from their gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android provides useful documentation on this particular case. [Compose an SMS/MMS message with attachment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Messaging)

**TLDR:**

Java

```
public void composeMmsMessage(String message, Uri attachment) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));  // This ensures only SMS apps respond
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Kotlin

```
fun composeMmsMessage(message: String, attachment: Uri) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
        data = Uri.parse("smsto:")  // This ensures only SMS apps respond
        putExtra("sms_body", message)
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment)
    }
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

**Example intent filter:**

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:type="text/plain" />
        <data android:type="image/*" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```